# How do I make contents of a tab widget in Qt automatically resize?

Tags: qt, user-interface

I'm trying to create a form with a nested Tab Widget in Qt Creator. The tree diagram of the contents looks like:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/NBSDPsR.png]

The tab widget itself resizes in accordance with the size of the parent window, which is good. 
What I want, though, is for the contents of the tabs - such as that graphicsView - to resize in accordance to the size of the tab which is modified by the size of the parent window.
It doesn't in this configuration, and adding intermediary containers inside the tab doesn't appear to solve the issue.

I notice that the layout icons at the tabs seem to indicate that it's disabled. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create some layout for your tabs (in case of single widget it doesn't matter which) to change layout for tabs of `QTabWidget` you just need to select desired tab in designer (and I mean selecting current tab visually on the form not in object inspector) and press button for desired layout at the top toolbar. I hope it would solve the problem.

Comment: OK, this sort of fixed my problem. Adding a layout to the Tab Widget (selected in the object explorer) when there was an object in the tab.  If there are no objects in the tab, I cannot make a layout, because all the options are greyed out. Further, it doesn't apply to any tabs that don't have objects in them even after the layout is specified. So I need to re-specify the layout each time I make a new tab and add something to it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks - I spent ages trying to apply a layout to a tab thinking I could select it in the object inspector. Selecting in the form window itself lets you apply form or grid layout or whatever. I wish Qt Designer would make it more clear that you have to select the tab visually first.

Comment: @AbuDhabi Thank you from 2021. :)